# CRF++ or CRFSuite

Tags: image-processing, android-activity, crf++, crfsuite

I'm starting to work with crf++ and crfsuite (both use a very similar file format). I want to do things related to images (segmentation, activiy recognition, etc). My main problem is how to build the training file. Has anybody work with crf and images? Has anybody explain me or give some file to learn.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

CRFsuite is  faster than CRF++ and it can deal with a huge training data. I tried both of them. They perfectly work on a reasonable amount of data, but when my dataset increased to be more than 100,000 sentences, CRF++ did not manage to deal with it and suddenly stopped working.
Look at the following link
[CRFsuite - CRF Benchmark test](http://www.chokkan.org/software/crfsuite/benchmark.html)
there is a comparison between many CRF software in some criteria

Answer (score 1):

I used CRF++ before and it worked very well.
But my field is natural language processing, and I use CRF++ for named entity recognition or POS tagging. CRF++ is easy to install on Linux but has some minor issue when compiling on windows.
You can just follow its document for training data format: each row represents a data sample and each column represents a feature type.

Or, you can also consider Mallet which has a CRF component.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you should start with the DGM library (https://github.com/Project-10/DGM), which is the best choice for those, who never worked with CRFs before. It includes a number of ready-to-go demo projects, which will classify/ segment your images just out-of-the-box. It is also well [documented](http://research.project-10.de/dgmdoc/).

Answer (score 0):

I have just came across this one for Windows:
http://crfsharp.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

maybe you also want to try CRF component in Mallet package.